# Monitor с защитой от взаимных блокировок

Tags: многопоточность, .net, синхронизация

Наиболее типичный вариант взаимной блокировки - это когда имеются два ресурса, которые блокируются двумя потоками в противоположном порядке.

Это же происходит в СУБД при работе двух транзакций, блокирующих две таблицы во взаимно противоположном порядке. Но Microsoft SQL Server умеет диагностировать эту ситуацию и предотвращает взаимную блокировку путём выкидыванием исключения.

Однако класс System.Threading.Monitor не предоставляет такой возможности. Я подумываю о том, чтобы сделать более продвинутую обёртку над ним. В связи с этим, у меня два вопроса:

- имеет ли это вообще смысл, или реализация такой проверки в базовом инструменте синхронизации убьёт производительность?
- Если имеет, то помогите мне поставить задачу - как сформулировать критерий, по которому можно диагностировать возможность взаимной блокировки.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163618.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Существует также *less intrusive* вариант - применение некоторых известных методов предотвращения блокировок на уровне *собственного проекта.*

Например, можно некоторую абстракцию `ResourceDispatcher` и следить за тем, чтобы диспетчеризация ресурсов происходила по схеме, не допускающей дедлоков.

***Пример тривиальной схемы*** - пронумеровать все общие ресурсы и запрещать потоку забирать ресурс с меньшим номером, чем минимальный номер ресурсов, забранных потоком. В случае, если это необходимо, то поток должен предварительно освободить все ресурсы с несоответствующими номерами.

---

За более *продвинутыми и производительными* методами предотвращения дедлоков, которые включают в себя всякие хитрости с построениями графов зависимостей и грамотным разрешением циклов в нем *(и прочими премудростями :)* стоит обратиться к гуглу.

*Могу поделиться референсами.*

Comment: Поделитесь.

Comment: На практике используют неблокирующий запрос ресурса или таймауты.

Answer (score 0):

Если взаимная блокировка возможна и критична (полностью разрушает работу приложения), то диагностировать ее нужно даже ценой потери производительности. Реально хорошо бы замерить, насколько снижается производительность при дополнительных проверках, разница может быть невелика.

В теории сама возможность взаимной блокировки проверяется путем построения конечного автомата, описывающего модель системы. Те состояния - замыкания, которые не имеют переходов вовне, могут быть состояниями взаимной блокировки.

Сверку состояния можно сделать, проверяя доступность тех ресурсов, которые блокируются, если они одновременно заняты, блокировка есть, не заняты - блокировки нет. Можно сделать эту проверку нечастой (в зависимости от того времени, которое система может быть блокированной).

**Добавил.**

Блокировка возникает, когда два потока обращаются к двум ресурсам в разном порядке так, что для завершения работы требуется занятый другим потоком ресурс. Есть смысл посмотреть модель системы, есть ли возможность объединить такие ресурсы без потери производительности; если есть, то такое объединение желательно.

Идея проверки блокировки такая: периодически, с максимально допустимым интервалом времени проверять одновременную доступность взаимно блокируемых пар ресурсов из выделенного потока, если оба одновременно заняты, блокировка есть и надо принудительно освободить ресурсы.

Comment: >> Если взаимная блокировка возможна и критична 

Мы сталкивались с ней в предыдущем проекте, и много времени убили на поиск места, где она затесалась. Если бы в этом месте вылетало исключение, это было бы гораздо проще локализовать.

>> насколько снижается производительность при дополнительных проверках

Собственно, вопрос в том, что нужно написать. На уровне общего решения, чтобы все блокировки проверялись автоматически.

>> Можно сделать эту проверку нечастой 
То есть, как периодический процесс? Но как отследить заблокированные ресурсы? Класс Monitor реализован через импортируемые функции.

Comment: А почему нельзя просто ввести какой-то натуральный порядок блокировки? Зачем вообще проверять таким странным способом? Нужно просто предотвратить возможность блокировки в неверном порядке..

Comment: Это в теории, когда все ресурсы блокируются в одном методе. А на практике взаимная блокировка обычно возникает, когда методы вызывают друг друга. И расстояние по стеку между ними может быть довольно большим, так что мысли о том, что там где-то что-то блокируется, просто не приходят в голову. Проблема не в том, как решить конкретную задачу с блокировками - проблема в том, как локализовать возникшую в большой системе ошибку.

Comment: А thread dumps на что? Я не знаю что там в .NET.. в Java такие ситуации можно обнаруживать разными автоматическими тулами (простые dead-локи между потоками).. думаю, в .NET такое тоже должно существовать. Они все основаны на анализе thread dump'ов (стеки вызовов являются частью дампа).

Comment: Managed Stack Explorer нужно прикреплять к процессу, как отладчик. А мне нужно исключение в логах, которые прислал тестер или заказчик, словивший баг.

Comment: Значит вам придётся из самого приложения делать регулярные стэк-трейсы и анализировать их на предмет дэдлоков и генерировать необходимый аутпут. Попробуйте копнуть в поисках аналога метода java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces только для .NET. Думаю, такие дампы можно делать сравнительно редко (если дэдлок случится, то это надолго и вряд ли кто-то моментально заметит и прибьёт всё раньше времени)